# Android SQLiteDatabase.insert vs SQLiteStatement.excuteinsert

Tags: android, sqlite

Which method is better for inserting a record to SQLite database in Android? and why?

`SQLiteDatabase.insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)`

or

`SQLiteStatement.excuteinsert()`

What is the fundamental difference between these two regardless of the syntax usage pattern?

Comment: ... or `executeSQL(mySQLCommandString, null);` or `executeSQL(mySQLCommandString, new String[]{value1, ..., valueN});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteStatement` allows you to prepare a statement once and to execute it repeatedly.
This might be more efficient when inserting many rows, but is usually not the bottleneck on mobile devices.